# Select option slide down when selecting deparment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried researching it but i was unable to find some thing that suited my need,Im fairly new to JQuery. What i need to to:
I have hidden the radio buttons and text with css. As the use chooses a department i want only those item in the radio buttons to show. but i need it to respond the user changes. Any suggestions?

```
    <p>
        Sub-Department:
    <select id="subdep">
        <option>Please Select Sub-Department</option>-->
        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
             <option value="inventory">Inventory Control</option>
        </select></p>
          </div><!--End of Sub-Department-->

<div id=taskcon>
<input type="radio" class="admin" value="Appt Exception"/>Appt Exception
<input type="radio" class="admin" value="Appt Reschedule"/>Appt Reschedule
<input type="radio" class="inventory" value="Inventory Review"/>Inventory Review
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var requestlist = document.getElementById("subdep");
var list = requestlist.options[requestlist.selectedIndex].value;

if(list == "Administration"){

    $('.admin').slideDown('slow');
}

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm, you're mixing native JS and jQuery. Why so?

Comment: should i keep it strictly JQ? I thought it might have been easier to target variables

Comment: Since you already using jQuery, why not use jQuery all the way? :) see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the liberty to correct your markup a little, as well as wrapping the text trailing each radio button with the `<label>` element, for usability reasons:

```
<div id="taskcon">
    <input type="radio" id="r1" class="admin" value="Appt Exception" /><label for="r1">Appt Exception</label>
    <input type="radio" id="r2" class="admin" value="Appt Reschedule" /><label for="r2">Appt Reschedule</label>
    <input type="radio" id="r3" class="inventory" value="Inventory Review" /><label for="r3">Inventory Review</label>
</div>
```

The `.admin` radio inputs and their accompanying `<label>`s can be hidden by using CSS or JS.:

```
.admin,
.admin + label {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
$(".admin, .admin+label").hide();
```

---

I have chosen to listen to the `.change()` event on the `<select>` element, and check the selected option's value to see if it matches "Administration":

```
$(function() {
    $("#subdep").change(function() {
        if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "Administration") {
            $(".admin, .admin+label").show();
        } else {
            $(".admin, .admin+label").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/f2MqE/

Answer (score 1):

> I have hidden the radio buttons and text with css.

Make sure when you "hide" them in CSS that you do it using `display: none;` because jQuery won't change `visibility: hidden;` to `visibility: visible;`.

[And here's some code for you](http://jsfiddle.net/bKZxH/):

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#subdep').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Administration") {
            $('#taskcon :not(.admin)').hide();
            $('#taskcon .admin').show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == "inventory") {
            $('#taskcon :not(.inventory)').hide();
            $('#taskcon .inventory').show();
        } else {
            $('.admin, .inventory').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Sub-Department:
        <select id="subdep">
            <option>Please Select Sub-Department</option>-->
            <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
            <option value="inventory">Inventory Control</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
<!--End of Sub-Department-->
<div id=taskcon>
    <input type="radio" class="admin" value="Appt Exception" id="aptex" />
    <label for="aptex" class="admin">Appt Exception</label>
    <input type="radio" class="admin" value="Appt Reschedule" id "aptrs" />
    <label class="admin" for="aptrs">Appt Reschedule</label>
    <input type="radio" class="inventory" value="Inventory Review" id="inv" />
    <label class="inventory" for="inv">Inventory Review</label>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.admin, .inventory {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have but when i select the item administrator noting is happening is it because i mixed Js and Jqury??

Comment: The code I posted is using jQuery exclusively but that's not what kept your code from working.  You were pulling from the `var requestlist = document.getElementById("subdep");`, which created the object for the select list, but it does it in the beginning (right when the document loads).  What you were missing was a way to bind the object to an event handler when it changed.